# How to delete duplicate records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried with this code but I don't know how I can do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `empleado-belgrano`
GROUP BY `nombre-belgrano`
HAVING COUNT(`nombre-belgrano`) AS `REPET` > 1   

UNION   

DELETE FROM `empleado-belgrano` 
WHERE `REPET` > 1
```

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near
'AS `REPET` > 1 UNION DELETE FROM `empleado-belgrano` WHERE `REPET` > 1' at line 4
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please don't write in ALL CAPS. It seems like you're shouting at us, and that is just rude and offensive - please fix it ASAP

Comment: Are you really using Microsoft SQL Server (the `sql-server` tag)? That seems like a MySQL error message.

Comment: The syntax isn't valid for SQL Server too; T-SQL doesn't use backticks for delimit Identifying.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are actually using MySQL, we can use a delete join here:

```sql
DELETE e1
FROM `empleado-belgrano` e1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `nombre-belgrano`, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM `empleado-belgrano`
    GROUP BY `nombre-belgrano`
) e2
    ON e2.`nombre-belgrano` = e1.`nombre-belgrano`
WHERE
    e2.cnt > 1;
```